# Problema con el uso de path de symfony en llamada ajax de jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony3, symfony, twig

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web con Symfony 3.4. Tengo una funcion que debe ejecutar una llamada ajax a un controlador y uso la funcion de jquery con tal fin. 
Estoy teniendo problemas al usar el **{{ path(' ') }}** en la url
La llamada ajax es la siguiente en mi archivo **turnos_filtrar.twig.js**:

```
        $.ajax
    ({
        async:true,
        method: 'GET',
        url: "{{ path('turnos_listar') }}",
       //url: '/turnos/listar',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend:iniciaEnvioTurnos,
        success: cargarFilasTurnos,
        timeout:11500,
        error : function() 
        {
            //desbloqueo la pagina
            $.unblockUI();

            //accedo al alert
            //var error = document.getElementById('error-turno');
            //seteo el msj
            //error.innerHTML = '<p>Error de conexión, por favor intente registrarse nuevamente más tarde</p>';
            //muestro
            //$('#error-turno').show();
            alert('ERROR DE CONEXIÓN, INTENTE NUEVAMENTE MAS TARDE');
        }
    });
```

La ruta a la que consulta es /turnos/listar y haciendo un debug:routing en consola obtengo

```
 turnos_listar              GET      ANY      ANY    /turnos/listar
```

La llamada funciona si uso la linea que esta comentada:

```
 //url: '/turnos/listar',
```

Pero no funciona cuando uso el {{ path('') }} , me interesa usarlo para ante cambios en el routing no se necesario cambiar manualmente los archivo js.
Gracias! Su ayuda es bienvenida!
Cristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Pude resolverlo de la siguiente forma:
En el template twig inclui el siguiente codigo:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        {% include 'scripts/panel turnos/turnos_filtrar.twig.js' %}
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Se modifico la estructura del proyecto, agregando una carpeta denominada *scripts* donde se ubicaran todos las llamadas ajax necesarias. En dicho directorio, se agrega el archivo *turnos_filtrar.twig.js*. Les copio una imagen de como queda estructurado el dir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para llamar el archivo donde tengo la llamada ajax. Modifique la url de la funcion ajax a la siguiente forma:

```
 $.ajax
    ({
        async:true,
        method: 'GET',
        url: "{{ path('turnos_listar') }}",
```

Como puede verse, ahora puedo usar el **{{ path(' ') }}** de twig. Ademas, el netbean me reconoce la sintaxis tanto de javascript,jquery y twig, lo cual es muy buen.
Espero que les sea util.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el problema está en la extensión del archivo.
El archivo debería finalizar con la extensión .twig así:

turnos_filtrar.js.twig

Siempre los he trabajado de esta forma y nunca he tenido ningún problema.

Saludos.